# ImportError: No module named gdal qgis2.8.1

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion, gdal-merge

i am using QGIS 2.8.1 (32 bit) in windows 7).
I imported two DEMs and trying to merge (QGIS>Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge)them.
Unfortunately it gives me import error as below.

***Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 37, in 
import gdal 
ImportError: No module named gdal***

How do I fix this in windows 7 32 bit environment?